# Section formula to find coordinate

Tags: vectors

$U = (4, 2, 3)$, $Q = (4, 2, 0)$

$N$ is the point on $UQ$ such that $UN = \frac{1}3UQ$

Without the section formula, I can see that $N = (4, 2, 2)$

But with the section formula:

$${3\begin{bmatrix}4\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}+ 1\begin{bmatrix}4\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}}\over{3 + 1}$$

$$= \frac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix}12\\6\\0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}4\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

$$= \frac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix}16\\8\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

Which gives $(4, 2, \frac{3}4)$ which is not correct

Comment: To get $UN=\frac{1}{3}UQ$ you want $UN=\frac{1}{2}NQ$, so you use $2,1$ not $3,1$. So you take $\frac{2}{1+2}\cdot U+\frac{1}{1+2}\cdot Q=(4,2,2)$. Note that it is *not* $\frac{1}{3}\cdot U+\frac{2}{3}\cdot Q$.

Comment: why is it 2 and not 3 when it states it is $1\over 3$

Comment: The formula you are trying to use is about the ratio of the two parts, not the ratio of one part to the whole.